# Confusion with Higher Order Functions in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning Higher Order Functions and their benefits. What I got so far is that HOFs allows to create generic function which we can reuse it for several relative operations, I hope I am right, why we need to pass function as parameter or return function to make function for generic functionality. Ok, if we want to make generic and reusable functions then why we need to pass function as parameter or return a function. Please guys help:(

Comment: Might want to take some of the negativity ("you can kill me but why on earth..."), and clue us in on "loads of articles".

Comment: Take a look at the following as just one example of a widely used higher order function and maybe it will help you sort out at least one of the reasons that they are quite useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Don't misunderstand. We're not mad at your ignorance: it's not like any of us was born knowing this stuff. But this question just isn't a good fit for SO without more context (and it seems from the wording that you knew that and posted it anyway). For the short version, every time you've ever added an event listener you've used an HOF. Now think about how you'd do it without being able to pass a function as a parameter.

Comment: "*why we need to pass function as parameter*" what about `element.addEventListener(someFunction)`? Or `someArray.sort(sortingFunction)`? Or `someArray.map(mappingRule)`?

Comment: I was just about to say what @VLAZ said. I think a really useful example of a higher order function in Javascript is [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Check out the use cases for that and it might help you understand why they can be useful.

Comment: @VLAZ, so we pass function to another function to add functionality or that function being passed to another function helps to do something Right??

Comment: @Dickens it lets us customise part of the other function's operation. In the case of `Array#sort`, for example you can define a different order via the sorting function - by default it's just lexicographical, so `[8, 11].sort()` returns `[11, 8]`. In a way, a callback is a way to do [the template method design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) but using functions instead of methods and inheritance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being higher order doesn't necessarily mean being generic (polymorphic). You can specifically accept Int => Int functions as a param and still be higher order. It just mean the function can take in another function as an argument.

There are many reasons for doing this, especially in the functional programming realm, however I am not going to get into the details of that and confuse you further, since that is a very big subject on its own.

Let's look at a few common use cases in Web Development (which is what I am guessing you are using JS for).

**Callbacks**

Callbacks, as the name suggests, are functions that you callback to when another function is done. Consider the following function.

```
function(argument1, callback){
   var result = doSomethingWithArgument(argument1)
   callback(result)
}
```

it derives something with its arguments and than passes it onto the callback.

Now the question might be, why can't we do this outside the function, or just derive the result inside the callback. One of the main reasons (besides performance implications), is the clarity.

In many cases we want to be call into different callback, or change the function we call into at runtime.

For example:

```
function("username", returnToLoginScreen)

function("username", returnToErrorScreen)
```

where returnTo... are functions that navigate you to another screen. If you look at *Ajax* calls, you will notice this is how they work

More on callbacks [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))

**Filter, Sort, Map etc.**

Another solid example is filter or sort. You want to be able to filter an array on different conditions. Say this is an Array of Objects and Objects have fields that are age, height etc.

Filter, being higher order, allows you to pass in different comparators, rather than requiring you to define a filter function for every possible criteria. Similarly you can define custom sorting strategies by passing in functions.

```
people.filter(a => a.height > 180) 
people.filter(a => a.age > 20)
```

The former will filter anyone who is shorter than 180cm in height and the latter will filter out anyone who is younger than 20.

There is no notion of "helping" as you suggested in the comments. We look at this from a Categorical perspective and don't necessary care how the function leverages it's parameter but only what it effects and returns. The function might be using it to "help itself" aka do something/get some result or it might simply be chaining it and calling into it as "the next step"

Comment: hey thanks for your kind explanation, might seem weird but bear with me. Imagine you are writing an app and in which situation you subconsciously tell yourself 'Here I have to create higher order function' Just what makes you think that you have to create higher order function :)

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't one clear answer to that. That is something you learn as a part of the experience you gain programming more and more. There are two extremely common use cases of higher order functions in web development, both of  which I have included above. 1) Callbacks, 2) Generic Functions that perform an ABSTRACT operation over a sub set of types (meaning the function can be called on a number of types and you don't exactly know the properties of these types a head of time) like filter, map etc. this is also common in some FP but dont confuse yourself with them yet

Answer (score 1):

This allows you to have a function that you can pass call back functions to. For example in jQuery you could do this `$(document).on("click",".my-class-selector", myFunction);` This would register `myFunction()` as a callback function whenever you click on something with `class="my-class-selector`.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, so e.g if we pass function a to function b then function a adds its functionality to function b just to help it??

Comment: Not really, no. In the case that I show above `$(document).on("click",".my-class-selector", myFunction);` the `.on()` function registers a "click" event on all html elements that have the "my-class-selector" class. Passing any of those click events to the `function myFunction(event) {` function.